# Sonar 3.2 analysis issue with SonarScmManager

Tags: sonarqube

This is my first question here. I have spent 3 days looking for answers and still nothing.

I'm using Hudson to get Sonar analysis for more then 30 projects. (They are building on the same environment)

Projects use mostly Ant. 
Hudson version: 2.1.2 
SCM Sync configuration plugin: 0.0.3

In several projects I get this kind of error:

---

```
INFO  .p.s.SonarScmManager - Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /export/hudson/workspace/project2/sources_for_sonar/a/ab/abc/abcd && svn --username user --password '****' --no-auth-cache --non-interactive --trust-server-cert blame --xml SomeKindOfJava.java
INFO  .p.s.SonarScmManager - Working directory: /export/hudson/workspace/project2/sources_for_sonar/a/ab/abc/abcd
INFO        org.sonar.INFO - Retrieve SCM info for /export/hudson/workspace/project2/sources_for_sonar/a/ab/abc/abcd/OtherJavaFile.java
WARN         o.s.p.s.Blame - Fail to retrieve SCM info of: /export/hudson/workspace/project2/sources_for_sonar/a/ab/abc/abcd/DiffJavaFile.java. Reason: The svn command failed.
20:19:59  couldn't set locale correctly
20:19:59  couldn't set locale correctly
20:19:59  /bin/sh: svn: not found
```

I have thought about the issue that svn has not been installed for the OS (Solaris) but wouldn't it affect all other projects as well not only some of them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this question relates to SonarQube. And the problem is quite clear. You need to make svn client available to your sonarQube analyzer

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
As I already explained: this is happening to some projects but not all, so I don't understand why svn client is available for some projects and for others aren't. Can you please explain in details where exactly I should make it available? And then to what it is related?